# Dataflow in Controllers & Layouts in Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework

I use a basic setup which uses a layout.phtml for the HTML Layout and view scripts for the content part.

I want to control some variables in the layout in my controllers, i.e. the title of my site.

How can I access my layout to output variables from within the controller?

Thanks for your feedback!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anything you assign to view in your controllers will be accessible both in view scripts and layout scripts - they use the same Zend_View.

As for setting the title of the page, simply use the HeadTitle view helper http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.view.helpers.html#zend.view.helpers.initial.headtitle

Answer (score 0):

```
$myLayout = Zend_Layout::getMvcInstance()->getView();
$myLayout->var = 'foo:bar';
```

in layout.phtml:

```
echo $this->layout()->var;
```

Comment: does not work, put the first one in my a controllers action and the second one in the layout.phtml without any changes